# What is the purpose of @Test annotation applied to a class in Scala?

Tags: eclipse, scala, testing, junit, scala-ide

I have a project in Java with JUnit tests in Scala. Each test class is annotated with `@Test`:

```
import org.junit.Test

@Test
class SomeTest {
  ...
}
```

[JUnit API](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) says that `@Test` is a method annotation. However, when I delete the `@Test` annotations from the classes while keeping method annotations intact, many tests are not executed when running from Eclipse.

So what is the purpose of `@Test` annotation applied to a class and why are some of the tests not run when these annotations removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala does not check the `ElementType` for annotations (even outside of Scala IDE), so there is no 'purpose' for a @Test annotation for a class in Scala.

In fact, you can apply any annotation to a class, Scala does not prevent this. Using the following example:

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Rule

@Rule
class Foo {
    @Test
    def test(filename: String) = println("test");
}
```

after compilation, you get a @Rule annotation on the class. This is a [known feature](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/ejU_Fnt2PW0/zOwtRkS-CWoJ), because AFAIK, you can 'apply' an annotation on a field in the source, but will actually end up on the method, if you use on of the [target annotations](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/target/package.html).

If you're running your tests through any of the standard test runners, the `@Test` on the class shouldn't make any difference. The only thing that counts is the `@Test` annotation on the method.

When you're using JUnit in Scala, you should follow the same rules as with Java.

Comment: Good explanation. My knowledge of Scala annotations is a bit hazy, and I didn't realise that the compiler deliberately ignores the `@Target` of Java annotations.

Answer (score 2):

The JUnit `@Test` annotation is a method annotation (see the source [here](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Test.java#L46)), **not** a class annotation. So not only is it unnecessary to add `@Test` to a class, it should not even be allowed.

It is weird that:

- Eclipse is even allowing you to add it to a Scala class.
- This is changing the behaviour of the tests.

Sounds like a bug in either Eclipse or, more likely, the Eclipse Scala plugin.

You say that many tests are not executed "when running from Eclipse". Does this mean that you can successfully run all the tests outside of Eclipse?

Comment: It's weird indeed. I can successfully run all the tests from the command line (using maven).

Comment: I am sure the scala plugin devs would love a bug report on this

Comment: @DanBurton as I say in my answer, the annotation thing is a general issue which isn't necessarily a bug, it's not specific to Eclipse.  For the junit within Eclipse, it's normal behaviour that the tests don't get run if you just have the annotation on the class. Scala-ide-dev uses the normal junit runners

Answer (score 1):

FYI with TestNG, you can specify `@Test` at the class level, and this will turn all the public methods of this class into tests. But yes, as far as I know, JUnit doesn't support this.